# Make QPainter paint on top of a content which is inside a QScrollArea and has been scrolled, in the correct position

Tags: qt, scroll, pyqt, pyside

I'm doing something cool with a custom `QWebView`, basically I paint a rectangle over the element which is under the mouse pointer, see:

[image: cool stuff]

However, if I scroll down and move the pointer again, it draws the rect on the wrong area. In the next screenshot the mouse is over the  which contains the search results, the top of the rectangle and the top of the `QWebView` have a big gap:

[image: the big gap]

What I did to insert this bug was simply calculating the position of the rect taking into account the horizontal and vertical scroll positions, I did this wrong calculation because the rect wasn't correctly positioned in regard to the content if I scrolled it. In both cases I have a rect painted in the wrong position if any scroll occurs.

So far, this is the code I have at the moment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# coding: utf-8
#                        VENI, SANCTE SPIRITUS

from PySide.QtWebKit import QWebView
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui


class CustomQWebView(QWebView):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Init the custom class
        """
        super(CustomQWebView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.currentframe = None
        self.lastelement = None
        self.lastelementboundingrect = None
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.setframeafterloadfinished)
        # default test pen
        self.defaultpen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.blue)
        self.defaultpen.setWidth(3)

    @QtCore.Slot(QtGui.QMouseEvent)
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        super(CustomQWebView, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

        if self.currentframe:
            hittestresult = self.currentframe.hitTestContent(event.pos())
            element = hittestresult.element()
            if self.lastelement != element:
                self.lastelement = element
                self.lastelementboundingrect = hittestresult.boundingRect()
                self.update()

    @QtCore.Slot(QtGui.QPaintEvent)
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        # draw the content first
        super(CustomQWebView, self).paintEvent(event)

        # then the rectangle
        if self.lastelementboundingrect:
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
            painter.setPen(self.defaultpen)
            # This rectangles takes into account any offset of the scroll bar
            # so the rectangle can be drawn correctly
            rect = QtCore.QRect()
            rect.setRect(self.lastelementboundingrect.x() +
                         self.currentframe.scrollPosition().x(),
                         self.lastelementboundingrect.y() +
                         self.currentframe.scrollPosition().y(),
                         self.lastelementboundingrect.width(),
                         self.lastelementboundingrect.height())
            # painter.drawRect(QtCore.QRectF(self.lastelementcurrectrect))
            painter.fillRect(
                QtCore.QRectF(rect), QtGui.QColor(255, 165, 0, 128))

    def setframeafterloadfinished(self):
        self.currentframe = self.page().mainFrame()
```

How can I correctly solve this positioning problem?

P.S.: Yes, the pointer don't appears in the screenshots because scrot cannot capture it, I did not realize before uploading the screenshots. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to subtract the x/y components of `page()->mainFrame()->scrollPosition()` from your rect's x/y components.

> This property holds the position the frame is currently scrolled to.